# mysql statement->fetch() failing while looping

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I have a rest API written using PHP (5.6.28) and Mysql. The thing I am trying to achieve is to pull 135k records from the database.

Query executes fine, I can get the number of rows fine. But while looping through the results and adding them to an array php stops execution with no errors.

I checked php errors (no errors recorded btw), increased max execution time (300secs), memory (256M) amount etc. The sql query works (finishes in 15secs)  when executed from mysql workbench. Php script dies in like 16secs.

How can we debug something like this? Or what is your solution? Below you can find the code.

```
set_time_limit(300); //allow php to run until query completes
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$sql = "SELECT client_delivery_item_dest_address1, client_delivery_item_dest_address3,  client_delivery_item_volume,
        client_delivery_item_transport_charge, client_delivery_item_waybill_number,client_deliveries.client_delivery_insert_date,
        client_delivery_item_barcode 
        FROM client_deliveries 
        INNER JOIN client_delivery_items ON client_deliveries.client_delivery_id = client_delivery_items.client_delivery_id              
        WHERE " . $date_where . " " . $branch_where . " 
        AND client_deliveries.source_branch_id=3 AND client_deliveries.is_transfer=0 
        ORDER BY client_delivery_insert_date ASC";

$statement = $this->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_result($client_delivery_item_dest_address1, $client_delivery_item_dest_address3, $client_delivery_item_volume,
                         $client_delivery_item_transport_charge, $client_delivery_item_waybill_number, $client_delivery_insert_date, $client_delivery_item_barcode);

//return array('sql' => $sql); used this to get the actual that is running

if (!$statement->execute()) {
    return array('error' =>  "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error); //execution doesnt fail apparently
}  

$statement->store_result();
//return array('rowcount' => $statement->num_rows); returns 134411 it is the correct number of rows

while ($statement->fetch()) {
    $delivery_item                   = array();            
    $delivery_item['store_code']     = $client_delivery_item_dest_address1;
    $delivery_item['store_city']     = $client_delivery_item_dest_address3;
    $delivery_item['volume']         = $client_delivery_item_volume;
    $delivery_item['price']          = $client_delivery_item_transport_charge;
    $delivery_item['waybill_number'] = $client_delivery_item_waybill_number;
    $delivery_item['delivery_date']  = $client_delivery_insert_date;
    $delivery_item['barcode']        = $client_delivery_item_barcode;
    array_push($delivery_items, $delivery_item);

    //return $delivery_items; returns first row correctly
} 

//the execution dies before here

$statement->close();
return $delivery_items;
```

Comment: used an iterator to check the memory usage amount after certain amount of rows processed, turns out that the script uses like 285mb of ram and script fails because of that. I increased the memory limit and it fixed the issue. Any idea on how to reduce memory consumption?

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, you exceeded the memory limit, which is 128MB by default in PHP 5.6.

You're fetching 135k rows. Note that `store_result()` transfers the *whole* result set into PHP's memory before you start fetching. In this mode, `fetch()` is really just iterating over the result set that is already in memory. So as you fill your `$delivery_items` array, you're essentially storing the result set in your memory twice.

An alternative is to call [use_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php), which does not pre-fetch the result set. Every call to `fetch()` fetches the next row from the MySQL server. This is a common way to decrease memory use when working with large result sets.

Then you're storing 135k rows in an array. Each row has seven fields. I'd guess some of them are numeric. You could try to convert these to binary representation, on the theory that native integers take less space than string representations of numbers.

```
$delivery_item['volume']         = (int) $client_delivery_item_volume;
```

I don't know your data, but this might be the only case where you can cast to an int. PHP also has a float type, but I don't recommend using float for currency values, because of rounding problems.

The only other suggestion I have is to avoid storing the entire array in memory, but structure your application so you can process each row one at a time. I'd do this by writing this function as a class implementing [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), to encapsulate the query and returns one row at a time as it fetches the row.